# How to access QmlStyling Nesting QtObjects?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to access nested QtObject in another Qml file.  [QmlStyling Nesting QtObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/QmlStyling#Nesting_QtObjects)

subDir/Style.qml file

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {

property int textSize: 40
property color textColor: "green"
property color rectColor: "red"

property QtObject window: QtObject {
    property color background: "white";
}

property QtObject border: QtObject {

    property QtObject width: QtObject {
        property int normal: 1;
        property int big: 3;
    }

    property QtObject color: QtObject {
        property color normal: "gray";
        property color focus: "blue";
        property color disabled: "red";
    }
}
}
```

I want to access it in Screen1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

import "subDir" 1.0

Item 
{
id: rootItem
width: 800; height: 600

Rectangle {
    id:myRect
    x: 47; y: 61
    width: 706; height: 478
    color: Style.rectColor // This works correctly
    //But this below line doesn't
    border.width: Style.border.width.big // I want to access something like this
}
}
```

In subDir/qmldir file:

```
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

qmldir and Style.qml files are in same folder (Just for info)

qml.qrc File:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
    <file>MainForm.ui.qml</file>
    <file>Screen1.qml</file>
    <file>subDir/qmldir</file>
    <file>subDir/Style.qml</file>
</qresource>
```